# Sharepoint 2010 multiple workflow status columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, nintex-workflow

We are using sharepoint 2010 along with desinger and nintex workflow. We found a behavior where multiple workflow status columns gets generated in library. Is there any specific reason, why multiple status columns gets generated or in which scenario these gets generated.

Thanks and regards,
Shardul Pasare

Answer (score 0):

Workflow columns get generated when republishing a workflow, the reason behind this is it keeps a record of historical versions of the workflows that are run. To remove them the following will need to be done.

Navigate to the library or content type using the workflow
Change the workflow settings and where all previous version workflows are
Select remove from the radio buttons and save the changes.

Your latest published workflow will be the one without the previous version title.

After doing this, if the workflow column is still there then attempt to remove it from the libraries columns manually

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But we observed that, if we publish workflow multiple times it is not always true that it will create new column only few cases it creates column. So in which scenarios it creates multiple columns?